# Problem mounting .ecryptfs home folder after entering correct passphrase!

Tags: mount, encryption, live-cd, ecryptfs

I have and encrypted `home` folder on my previous OS (Lubuntu 18.04) which is not bootable now and need to recover it from Live OS. When I run following command to decrypt my `home` folder:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private --rw /media/lubuntu/<UUID>/.ecryptfs/<USERNAME>/.Private/
```

it returns:

```
INFO: Found [/media/lubuntu/<UUID>/.ecryptfs/<USERNAME>/.Private/].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase:
```

and after entering correct passphrase, it gives following error:

```
Inserted auth tok with sig [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] into the user session keyring
mount: /tmp/ecryptfs.XXXXXXXX: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.XXXXXXXX].
```

Someone could explain for me what is the problem and how it could be solved?

Comment: Is this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1718658/comments/26 helpful?

Comment: @nobodyThank you very much, your comment solved my problem, please write it as an answer and please explain what is the problem in fact and how this command solve the problem.

Comment: sadly I can not, it is to complicated for me in english. :(